# using Google wideVine for remote application verification

Tags: windows, security, kernel, drm, tpm

I'm working on a network application and I'd like to use an existing DRM solution in order to verify the agent from the server side.

In specific, there are some HTTPS based requests that used for authentication or passing sensitive data and I wish to verify their sender from the server side.

For that I need some DRM solution that already exists in the machine like and uses some low level security item like the TPM or built-in kernel driver so it'll be hard to temper with.

Implementing DRM without any 3rd party, will be based on obfuscation since a root-privileged user may have access to the original application certificates and private keys, as well as the ability to monitor the SSL based communication using local proxy.

Perhaps anyone can tell me if there's any such solution available ? Can I use google WideVine for this job, and if yes, is it mandatory to have Chrome to do that ?